# Update a column in table based on formula given in another column Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 4 columns :

```
Col1  Col2      Col3       Col4
1      2      Col1+Col2     3
3      4      Col1*Col2     12
6      3      Col1/Col2     2
```

Col1, Col2 and would have some values, col3 would have a formula and based on that formula I need to populate values in col4. I have tried it using dynamic SQL which works row by row but I have millions of records in my table and it is taking forever to execute the script. Please suggest the simplest and fastest way to handle this scenario.

Comment: How complicated are the formulas?  SQL is not really suitable for this type of processing.

Comment: Normal Arithmetic operations only. There might be multiple columns though like col1 +col2 /Col3 * Col4.

Comment: Nothing "simple" or "fast" here. You are essentially defining a language in [Col3], and you will have to create a parser. This is no easy task.

Comment: Does your table have a primary key? Batch iteration might be of some help here.

Comment: @PiyushBhardwaj [this](https://github.com/zzzprojects/Eval-SQL.NET/wiki/SQL-Server-Eval-%7C-Dynamically-evaluate-arithmetic-operation-and-expression-in-SQL#sql-eval---arithmetic--math-expression) might be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an update query for each operator if you only have a single operator in the column +,-,/,*

Depending on the distribution of the data solving the simple operations first in bulk, will speed up the process

```
-- Bulk operation for Col1 * Col2
UPDATE Table
    Set Col4 = Col1 * Col2
WHERE LEN(Col4) - LEN(REPLACE(Col4, '*', '')) = 1 -- Only has one *
AND Like 'Col1%'
AND Like '%Col2'
-- Doesn't have other operator
AND NOT LIKE '%+%'
AND NOT LIKE '%*%'
AND NOT LIKE '%/%'
```

You could generate these queries using [T4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019) if you have multiple columns/combinations.

For multiple operators you will need a parser because you need to take care or order of operators and other rules.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the (very) rare cases where a cursor is appropriate.  In fact, this is rather complicated -- an updatable cursor along with dynamic SQL.

Here is the idea:

```
declare @col1 int;
declare @col2 int;
declare @col3 nvarchar(max);
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
declare @col4 int;


DECLARE c CURSOR
FOR SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM t FOR UPDATE;

OPEN c;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @col1, @col2, @col3;

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    set @sql = 'select @col4=[col3] from (select @col1 as col1, @col2 as col2) t';
    
    set @sql = replace(@sql, '[col3]', @col3);
    
    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@col1 int, @col2 int, @col4 int output',
                       @col1=@col1, @col2=@col2, @col4=@col4 output;

    SELECT @col1, @col2, @col3, @col4;
    
    UPDATE t
        set col4 = @col4
        WHERE current of c;
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @col1, @col2, @col3;
END;

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
```

And [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4552cc32bf35ddf0b9f05443a695a462) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that this will not be speedy.  Getting performance on such a query is quite difficult, but you can break the table up into chunks and update each chunk using a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your approach and work in set based mode, using also programming language as C#

With running total query you can calculate the distribution of your data and work with chunk of x records to update by Col3. In order not to have lock escalation I advise to work with 1000 rows at a time.
Example for running total query:

https://codingsight.com/calculating-running-total-with-over-clause-and-partition-by-clause-in-sql-server/

Now, you can update Col4 with equal chunk (calculated before) using Col3 as condition in a C# cycle or other programming languages (you can also use a while loop in SQL but it isn’t recommended)

P.S. check your indexes before to run the procedure

Answer (score 0):

If the expressions in `col3` are syntactically correct in a way SQL server can understand and execute them, you can use dynamic SQL. Create a query with a `CASE` expression. In the case expression, every branch checks for the string value of `col3` and returns the respective expression. You just need as many branches as there are distinct expressions.

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT @query = concat('UPDATE elbat', nchar(13), nchar(10),
                       '       SET col4 = CASE', nchar(13), nchar(10),
                       (SELECT DISTINCT
                               concat('                    WHEN col3 = ''', col3, '''', nchar(13), nchar(10),
                                      '                      THEN ', col3, nchar(13), nchar(10)) [text()]
                               FROM elbat
                               FOR XML PATH(''),
                                       TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
                       '                  END;')
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM elbat);

PRINT @query;

EXEC(@query);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=e9a7f93822c924aecb67a4870548cf34)